# BeautifulSoup: find all tags with a given attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

With BS4, how can I search for all tags that have a given attribute `data-path`? I.e, how can I search for an attribute without specifying an element (as I don't want to assume specific elements) or an attribute *value*?

This returns nothing:

```py
parser.find_all(attr='data-path')
```

Comment: i think tag name is required for above method can you provide URL with desired output so it will be easy to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter function:

```py
parser.find_all(lambda tag: tag is not None and tag.has_attr("data-path"))
```